# A little bit confused about javascript promise

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to make my code working using a promise.

Reading and playing out, created the followed peace of code trying to set some properties in "githubUserData" object. Promise seems to be working but "githubUserData" returns {} (empty)

Obviously as my console log shows, my code didn't executed with desired order. It displays the object before his properties set..

```
    console.clear();
    console.log( '>>>>>> Starting promise..' );

    // Create object to keep requested data
    let githubUserData = {};

    function getGithubUserData() {
        // Promise
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.github.com/users/codepen',
                data: {},
                success: function( data ) {
                    resolve( data ); // Resolve promise and go to then()
                },
                error: function( err ) {
                    reject( err ); // Reject the promise and go to catch()
                }
            });
        });
    };

    getGithubUserData().then( data => {
      // Promise request was successful
      console.log( '>>>>>> Data: ', data);
      console.log( '>>>>>> Data loaded: ' + data.id + ', ' + data.name + ', ' + data.type + ', ' + data.blog );
      githubUserData = {...data};
    }).catch( err => {
      // Promise rejected via reject()
      console.log( err );
    })

    console.log('>>>>>> Promise end. Data saved: ', githubUserData);
```

codepen pen for this..
https://codepen.io/snart1/pen/KOXbNr?editors=0012

What i am doing wrong here?

How to execute my code not with following order

```
1. >>>>>> Starting promise..
2. >>>>>> Promise end. Data saved:  Object {}
3. >>>>>> Data loaded: 1545643, CodePen, Organization, http://codepen.io
```

but this (having data in object)

```
1. >>>>>> Starting promise..
2. >>>>>> Data loaded: 1545643, CodePen, Organization, http://codepen.io  
3. >>>>>> Promise end. Data saved: Object { data here }
```

PS. I prefer a JavaScript solution, not jQuery.

**UPDATE**
I tried the async/await, too, but getting the same result (this code is closer to my goal).

```
console.clear();
console.log( '>>>>>> Starting promise..' );

// Create object to keep requested data
let githubUserData = {};

async function getGithubUserData() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Promise
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
                if ( xhr.status >= 300 ) {
                    reject( "Error, status code = " + xhr.status );
                } else {
                    resolve( JSON.parse( xhr.responseText ) );
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.open( 'get', 'https://api.github.com/users/codepen', true );
        xhr.send();
    });
}
async function logUserData() {
    try {
        let data = await getGithubUserData();
        console.log( '>>>>>> Data loaded: ' + data.id + ', ' + data.name + ', ' + data.type + ', ' + data.blog );
        githubUserData = {...data};
    } catch ( err ) {
       console.log( err );
    }
}
logUserData();

// My goal is to have githubUserData loaded with data here !!!!
console.log( '>>>>>> Promise end. Data saved: ', githubUserData );
```

codepen pen for async/wait 
https://codepen.io/snart1/pen/ymzQvK?editors=0012

Is there any way to have data here, console.log('>>>>>> Promise end. Data saved: ', githubUserData);
not inside getGithubUserData call, but after? Is there any way to hold execution of the script till having data there?
That's my goal, to get data there..

Comment: Your final console.log is running synchronously so it executes before your async function has resolved. FYI, $.ajax returns a deferred Promise so you're wrapping a promise around an already asynchronous method.

Comment: note: `$.ajax` returns a "thenable" (I wouldn't call it a Promise, but it's close enough) therefore, you can remove the `success` and `error` properties, and just return `$.ajax(....)`

Comment: guys in my code i am using xtmhttpRequest.. I used ajax here for a shorten code..

Comment: It won't solve the issue but you should gain some insight by moving `console.log( '>>>>>> Starting promise..' )` immediately above `console.log('>>>>>> Promise end. Data saved: ', githubUserData)`. You will find that nothing has changed. And the reason nothing has changed is that `githubUserData = {...data}`, in the `.then()` callback, runs in a *later* javascript thread, some time after those `console.log()` statements have executed. That is, in a nutshell, the essence of `.then()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're logging before the `then` is executed. Use `finally` like so.

```
getGithubUserData().then(...).catch(...).finally(() => {
  console.log(githubUserData);
});
```

The asynchronous code which assigned the data to the variable was being run after you actually logged the variable.

`finally` is used so you can see an output regardless of whether an error is caused or not.

Comment: Is there any way to have data here,  
console.log('>>>>>> Promise end. Data saved: ', githubUserData);
not inside getGithubUserData call, but after?
Is there any way to hold execution of the script till having data there?

Comment: If you enclose it all in an `async` function, then yes.